# Вызов сохраненного запроса с MySQL при помощи PHP

Tags: php

Всем добрый вечер! Возник небольшой вопрос по поводу использования в коде php вызова сохраненных процедур, хранимых на сервере MySQL . Вот к пример классического вывода запроса: Код PHP 1 $result=mysqlquery('SELECT * FROM tbl1'); Все работает отлично и замечательно, но.... У меня есть к примеру уже такой запрос на самом сервере MySQL , который я сохранил под букмаркой ZAPROSIK. Чтобы не писать постоянно полный текст запроса типа SELECT....... как можно обратиться к хранимому запросу на сервере?? Вариант с : Код PHP 1 $result=mysqlquery('ZAPROSIK'); не прокатывает.

То есть как правильно работать с этой букмаркой. У меня просто есть сложные запросы на объединение , строк этак в 25 , они сохранены под разными именами на серваке. Вместо того чтобы писать эти строки в коде php , как можно обратиться просто к имени этого сохраненного запроса на MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("call ZAPROSIK()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы имели в виду хранимые процедуры и функции? Или [Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html)?

см. [Using Stored Routines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html)

Answer (score 0):

В MySQL ни хранимые процедуры ни функции не возвращают результат выполнения в виде таблицы. Сохранить свой запрос ты мог только как `VIEW`. На уровне обращения к базе, работа с `VIEW` выглядит как работа с обычной таблицей. То есть: `SELECT * FROM ZAPROSIK`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующий код:

$query = "SELECT * FROM ZAPROSIK";

$result = mysql_query($query);

Сам его использую и все работает нормально.